# Laravel: mysql Get all Unread and 15 last unread notification in json

Tags: mysql, json, laravel

I am working on Notification system in application and I am stuck to get All unread notification + last 15 read notification also I have sorting problem in html it giving axact result in json but when I am embeding in html it sorting automatic :(

**Here is my Laravel Code:**

```
public function ajaxNotificaitons() {
    $customFunctions = new \admin\library\myFunctions;
    $where = array('send_to' => Auth::user()->id);
    $notifications = Notification::where($where)->orderby('id', 'desc')->get();

    // return $notifications;
    $jsonData = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($notifications as $notification) {
        $data = $customFunctions->getUserDetail($notification->send_by);
        $row = array();
        $row['id'] = $notification->id;
        $row['order_id'] = $notification->order_id;
        $row['message'] = $notification->message;
        $row['send_by'] = $data['username'];
        $row['send_to'] = $notification->send_to;
        $row['is_read'] = $notification->is_read;
        $row['is_hidden'] = $notification->is_hidden;
        $row['is_deleted'] = $notification->is_deleted;
        $row['date'] = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($notification->created_at));
        $row['time'] = date('H:i:s', strtotime($notification->created_at));
        $jsonData[$i++] = $row;
    }

    return Response::json($jsonData);
    // return json_encode($jsonData);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this should work:

```
    Notification::where('send_to', Auth::user()->id)->where('status', 'unread')->union(Notification::where('send_to', Auth::user()->id)
                             ->where('status', 'read')
                             ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                             ->limit(15)
                             ->getQuery()
)->get();
```

You probably want to edit this to suite your needs.

Comment: FatalErrorException in NotificationsController.php line 31:
syntax error, unexpected ';' :( ->limit(15);

Comment: @hy_sultani Fixing a simple syntax error should be entirely within your abilities.

Comment: @hy_sultani Oh there shouldn't be a simicolon after limit also you need to after `getQuery()` after `limit()`. See edited answer.